# websphere .net client login different user

Tags: ibm-mq

Hi I want to login different credentials to wepshere mq from my pc.The error message like that.

```
The call to initialize the User ID 'mypcuser' failed with CompCode 2 and Reason 
2035. If an MQCSP block was used, the User ID in the MQCSP block was 'mydifferentuser' user'. 
ACTION: 
Correct the error and try again.
```

In error I see both user of my differentuser and mypcuserboth

My code and my setting properties like that ,How can I login wephshere mq with given username and password authentication

```
public Hashtable init(String connectionType, string hostName, string channel)
    {
        Hashtable connectionProperties = new Hashtable();

        // Add the connection type
        // connectionProperties.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, connectionType);

        connectionProperties.Add(MQC.USER_ID_PROPERTY, "mydifferentuser");
        connectionProperties.Add(MQC.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "xxx");
        connectionProperties.Add(MQC.CONNECTION_NAME_PROPERTY, hostName);
        connectionProperties.Add(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY,  channel);
        connectionProperties.Add(MQC.MQADPCTX_YES,1);
....
        MQQueueManager qMgr = new MQQueueManager(QueueManagerName, connectionProperties);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
connectionProperties.Add(MQC.USER_ID_PROPERTY, "username");
connectionProperties.Add(MQC.PASSWORD_PROPERTY,"****");
connectionProperties.Add(MQC.USE_MQCSP_AUTHENTICATION_PROPERTY, true);
```

these properties must set client .net code.

and in webpsheremq side username must be setto mca field.And user must have right in computer.

Comment: You could also set `ADOPTCTX(YES)` on the `AUTHINFO` object, this will tell the queue manager to use the ID you authenticated as for MQ permission (OAM) checks instead of the user you are running as.  With how you have it configured anyone that has the ability to authenticate to the queue manager will be able to access that channel and permissions of whatever the `MCAUSER` on the channel is set to.

Comment: Hi I can't find where I can set this info in my client code,can you share a simple   code block

Comment: Is it necessary to set MCAUser or changing ADOPTCTX(YES) on the AUTHINFO is enoug?

Comment: There are different layers that you reference.  The `MCAUSER` of the channel would be used of `CONNAUTH` was not used and is always a good idea to put in some invalid value such as `*NOACCESS`.  If `CONNAUTH` is used with `ADOPTCTX(YES)` then the user authenticated will override the value in the `MCAUSER`.

Comment: You should also consider that if you do not have the `AUTHINFO` object configured with `CHKCLNT(REQUIRED)` that anyone can connect with out a username and password.  In some cases you may have a mix of `SVRCONN` channels where you want to require `CONNAUTH` or not, this would require setting `CHKCLNT(OPTIONAL)` on the `AUTHINFO` and then using `CHLAUTH` records to uplift to `CHKCLNT(REQUIRED)` for those channels where it is required.  Also note that `CHLAUTH` `USERSRC(MAP)` rules have no effect with `ADOPTCTX(YES)` as the user passed is always used.